# deliminator column values in SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table(3 columns: numeric,numeric,string) in PostgreSQL the form of -

```
100226, 118, "{{5662,"IBM Certified for On Demand Business - Solution Advisor - 816"},{5663,"MS Windows XP Desktop Administration   -  Assessment - E1"},{5664,"MS Windows 95 Navigation   -  Assessment - E3"},{5671,"TestPrep Final Exam: Six Sigma Foundations"}"
```

Now me requirement is get the row in the form as below

```
100226    118    {5662,"IBM Certified for On Demand Business - Solution Advisor - 816"}
                 {5663,"MS Windows XP Desktop Administration   -  Assessment - E1"}
                 {5664,"MS Windows 95 Navigation   -  Assessment - E3"}
                 {5671,"TestPrep Final Exam: Six Sigma Foundations"}
```

Below is the query through which I am retrieving the values

```
select
    chs.lms_im_employee_id emp_num,
    chs.lms_mr_cp_id complaince_no,
    entity_name
from
    lms.lms_im_cmplnc_objtemp obj,
    lms.lms_im_cmplnc_history chs
where
    obj.lms_mr_cp_id=chs.lms_mr_cp_id
    and  obj.lms_im_employee_id = chs.lms_im_employee_id      
    and chs.lms_im_ch_is_compliant = false 
    and  chs.lms_im_employee_id  = '66'
group by chs.lms_mr_cp_id, chs.lms_im_employee_id;
```

Comment: What is the Postgresql version? `select version()`

Comment: "EnterpriseDB 9.3.1.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 64-bit"

Answer (score 0):

First, if possible, storing your string would be beneficial, but if not,
try the following

Now, your data looks a little bit malformed in that it's missing a final }. In this answer, I assume that's a mistake, if it is not, you're going to have to clean up your data, or rewrite my query to append '}' on the end of the raw data.

```
select
    chs.lms_im_employee_id emp_num,
    chs.lms_mr_cp_id complaince_no,
    json_array_elements(array_to_json(entity_name::text[])) entity_name
from
    lms.lms_im_cmplnc_objtemp obj,
    lms.lms_im_cmplnc_history chs
where
    obj.lms_mr_cp_id=chs.lms_mr_cp_id
    and  obj.lms_im_employee_id = chs.lms_im_employee_id      
    and chs.lms_im_ch_is_compliant = false 
    and  chs.lms_im_employee_id  = '66'
group by chs.lms_mr_cp_id, chs.lms_im_employee_id;
```

or, if your data is in fact missing the closing }

```
select
    chs.lms_im_employee_id emp_num,
    chs.lms_mr_cp_id complaince_no,
    json_array_elements(array_to_json((entity_name||'}')::text[])) entity_name
from
    lms.lms_im_cmplnc_objtemp obj,
    lms.lms_im_cmplnc_history chs
where
    obj.lms_mr_cp_id=chs.lms_mr_cp_id
    and  obj.lms_im_employee_id = chs.lms_im_employee_id      
    and chs.lms_im_ch_is_compliant = false 
    and  chs.lms_im_employee_id  = '66'
group by chs.lms_mr_cp_id, chs.lms_im_employee_id;
```

of course all of this assumes that your data is formatted perfectly. If it isn't then you're going to have to either clean up your data, or write a custom function to interpret it.